# Exercício de implementação de lista sequencial

Tags: java, lista, estrutura-de-dados

Estou tentando resolver este exercício da faculdade no qual já implementei boa parte, porém falta ainda 3 coisas. É sobre estrutura de dados com Java OO - lista sequencial.

Segue o código da classe da lista:

```
public class ListaSequencial {
    private Contato [] contatos = new Contato[10];
    private int n = 0;


    boolean isVazia(){
        return n == 0;
    }

    boolean isCheia(){
        return n == contatos.length;
    }

    int tamanho(){
        return n;
    }

    private void deslocaDireita(int pos){
        for(int i = n; i > pos;i--){
            contatos[i] = contatos[i - 1];
        }
    }

    boolean inserir(Contato contato){
        if(isCheia()){
            return false;
        }

        contatos[n] = contato;
        n++;
        return true;

    }
    boolean inserir(Contato c, int pos){
        if(isCheia()){
            return false;
        }
        deslocaDireita(pos);
        contatos[pos] = c;
        n++;
        return true;
    }

    private void deslocaEsquerda(int pos){
        for(int i = pos; i < n - 1 ;i++){
            contatos[i] = contatos[i+1]; 
        }
    }

    boolean remover(int pos){

        if(pos < 0 || pos >=n){
            return false;
        }
        deslocaEsquerda(pos);
        n--;
        return true;
    }


    public String imprimir(){
        String str = "";
        if(isVazia()){
            return "lista vazia";
        }
        else{
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                str += contatos[i].nome + " - " + contatos[i].telefone + "\n";   
            }
            return str;
        }
    }


    Contato buscar(int pos){
        if(pos < 0 || pos >= n){
            return null;
        }
        return contatos[pos];
    }

    int getPosicao(Contato contato){

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if(contatos[i] == contato){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

O que não sei fazer e preciso para o Exercício:

1. Preciso criar um método para concatenar 2 listas;
2. Preciso criar um método que assim que a lista encha, crie um container (vetor) maior fazendo com que ela nunca encha (tipo um laço);
3. Por fim, preciso de um método pra remover um elemento da lista passando ao invés do índice, o próprio elemento. No caso, que remova a primeira ocorrência encontrada.

Alguém me dê uma ajuda?

Comment: Olá. Seja bem-vindo ao SOPt. Está um pouco confuso. O que você não sabe? O algoritmo? Além disso, você tem muitas perguntas numa só. Faça o nosso [tour] e no guia de [como fazer uma boa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Sinta-se à vontade para editar a pergunta acrescentando detalhes.

Comment: Bom reformulei a pergunta no fim para entenderem melhor, o algoritmo eu sei porém não sei fazer os 3 metodos que coloquei no final. ( O de concatenar, criar um metodo para que a lista assim que encher criar um vetor maior e Remover um elemento da lista passando o proprio elemento. A linguagem já sei varias coisas mas ao meu ver ainda sou iniciante e estou ''Aprendendo a força" estrutura de Dados.

Answer (score 2):

(3) Este é o mais fácil. Faça o seguinte:

- Crie o novo método para excluir o elemento, o retorno é `boolean`.
- Percorra o array usando um `for`. Os elementos a serem percorridos são de 0 até `< n`.
- Verifique dentro do seu for se aposição do array correspondente tem o elemento que você está procurando. Se tiver, use o `remover(int)` para remover esta posição e retorne `true` logo em seguida.
- Para decidir se o elemento encontrado é o que você procura ou não, recomendo que utilize o método `java.util.Objects.equals(Object a, Object b)`.
- Se você terminar de percorrer o array e não encontrar o elemento, retorne `false`.

(2) Fazer a lista crescer é o mais complicadinho dos três. Faça o seguinte:

- Faça o método `isCheia()` ser privado. O motivo disso é que do ponto de vista externo da classe, a lista nunca fica cheia, vez que quando ela encher, ela vai aumentar e não mais continuar cheia, e portanto este método já não faria mais sentido para quem está olhando a classe de fora.
- Crie um método privado `crescer()`, que é responsável por fazer o array interno crescer de tamanho. Para isso você cria um array maior que o antigo, copia todos os elementos e troca a referência (`contatos = novoArray;`).
- Ao invés de `if (isCheia()) { return false; }`, faça `if (isCheia()) { crescer(); }`.
- Os métodos `inserir` passam a ter retorno `void`.

(1) Para criar o método que concatena duas listas faça isso:

- Esse item é muito mais fácil se você tiver feito a parte 2 primeiro. Antes de implementar o item 1, faça o item 2.
- Crie um método estático que receba como parâmetro as duas listas e retorne uma lista.
- Este método cria uma lista nova. Percorre os `lista1.n` elementos da primeira lista e os adiciona na lista nova. Depois ele percorre os `lista2.n` elementos da segunda lista e faz a mesma coisa.
- Retorne a nova lista criada.

Comment: Amigo, não teria como postar em código ?

Comment: @RomárioJúnior Sim, teria. Mas como isso é um exercício de faculdade para você aprender, acredito que a ideia seja você conseguir escrever o código você mesmo para garantir o aprendizado.

Comment: A idéia é essa mesmo, porém como é um Academico Virtual só tenho mais alguns minutos para fazer a postagem do restante do Exercicio e a Atividade fechar, tentei fazer alguma coisa mas ainda tenho dificuldade . Ajudaria muito se postasse .